# How can I keep a log of NullReferenceException errors that occur in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Occasionally a developer will not instantiate a required part of a viewmodel and the corresponding razor view will throw a NullReferenceException error. From there, customErrors redirects to a generic server error 500 view.

I want to log that error in a repository so these incidents can be discovered and fixed. Is there part of the framework that can handle this?

Comment: Add [ELMAH](https://github.com/alexbeletsky/elmah-mvc) it works like a black box for exceptions which you can review at leisure. You can configure it to store logs in memory or disk

Comment: I would go for ELMAH as well: http://blog.elmah.io/elmah-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logging frameworks like ELMAH or LOGNet, which are great tools but sometimes you just want to shove it into a database or send a simple email. To manage something like that I have found the best solution is to create a base controller that all of your controllers will inherit from and override the following:

```
protected override async void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
}
```

Anytime an exception handles in the view or in the controller it will hit here before doing anything. You can still even have other frameworks work with this also.